# How to detect current JSF-Version?

Tags: jsf, version, detection

I am developing a jsf-webapp and now I need to know what JSF-Version I am using? Where can I look this up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Programmatically, you mean? You can get it from [`Package#getImplementationVersion()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVersion%28%29).

```
String version = FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

There are by the way also [`getImplementationVendor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationVendor%28%29) and [`getImplementationTitle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getImplementationTitle%28%29) methods. You might want to use it as well in order to distinguish the vendor (MyFaces or Mojarra, for example).

Or do you mean manually? Just look in `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file of the JSF impl JAR file. You can extract the JAR file with a ZIP tool. It's the `Implementation-Version` entry of the manifest file.

Comment: Just as a note, it appears that the MyFaces implementation included with WebSphere (8.5.0.2 at least) does not have values set for the implementation version, vendor, etc. You may wish to supplement above with code to print out the actual jar loaded for FacesContext (and Facelet):
`System.out.println("JSF API Location: " + FacesContext.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());`
`System.out.println("JSF Impl Location: " + Facelet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());`

Comment: Worked for me in JSF2.2, but returns null in JSF 2.3

Comment: Just for the records: recent [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/) versions provide in the utility class [`Faces`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Faces) the method [`getImplInfo()`](https://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.6/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#getImplInfo--), which returns exactly what is described in this answer. This is also available in EL via `#{faces.implInfo}`.

Comment: And the primefaces version? Is there possible programmaticaly?

Answer (score 2):

For me it wasn’t working with a **WebSphere Server**, so I followed the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125782/how-to-detect-current-jsf-version#comment34884636_13125869) of peater:

```
System.out.println("JSF API Location: " + FacesContext.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());
System.out.println("JSF Impl Location: " + Facelet.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());
```

It showed me the version in the filename of the library:

JSF API Location: (file:/C:/workspaces/spielwiese/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.websphere.javaee.**jsf.2.2_1.0.18**.jar )

JSF Impl Location: (file:/C:/workspaces/spielwiese/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.websphere.javaee.**jsf.2.2_1.0.18**.jar )

Comment: Get only the version: FacesContext.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().toString().replaceAll("^.*faces-(\\d.*\\d).*$", "$1")

Answer (score -4):

**steps**

1: unzip javax.faces.jar (extract to a folder),go to extract
    folder\META-INF

2:   in side META-INF ,open MANIFEST.MF.

3:   search for Implementation-Version

for example : **Implementation-Version: 2.1.6-SNAPSHOT**