# <f:ajax listener="#{bean.selectPlan}" call to @PostConstruct before execute the selectPlan method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a `check box` in my application and I want to call selectPlan method to execute when user select the `check box`

But when ever I select the `check box` it call the `@PostConstruct` method before the selectPlan method.

This leads to unwanted calls to back end as I have written some functions to populate data when page load in the `@PostConstruct`

```
<td>
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{plan.checked}">
         <f:ajax listener="#{planOverlay.selectPlan}" render=":overlayForm:myTable"/>
      </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</td>
```

Below is the bean class

```
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

 @ManagedBean(name = "planOverlay")
 @ViewScoped
 public class PlanOverlayBean extends OverlayBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       super.init();

       loadPlansFrom_DB();
    }

    public void selectPlan(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws Exception {
       getOverlay().getService().setSelectedPlan(rowdata);
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC     I checked this but I confirm my `ViewScope` is using `import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;`

Comment: Who's managing the bean? That annotation would only work along with JSF specific `@ManagedBean` from same package.

Comment: @BalusC    I updated the full class details including import statements

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Does the problem also manifest when you've **only** a `<h:body><h:form><h:selectBooleanCheckbox><f:ajax>` in a test page?

Comment: @BalusC    Yes, Still it loads the bean.

Comment: Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: @BalusC    I'm not sure how to check the version correctly. I think this is `jsf 2.0`. I found a `faces-config.xml` also in `WEB-INF`  folder

Comment: Check JSF version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13125869/4074715

Comment: @BalusC   It prints The version as  1.0.0.0_2-1   when I use `FacesContext.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`

Comment: Looks like a server-modified/managed JSF 2.1 implementation. The exact JSF 2.1 implementation and version should then be determined based on exact server make/version (provided you didn't upgrade/change the server-bundled JSF). I only don't suspect a JSF impl/version specific bug anymore as that would otherwise obviously affect all other users of same server make/version (and being able to use @ViewScoped is a very very important feature). Perhaps you're victim of classpath pollution? Do you have any JSF-related JARs in /WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @BalusC   I have `jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar` inside the `WEB-INF/lib` and also these jars in the same place `httpclient-4.1.2.jar,  httpcore-4.1.2.jar, json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar, primefaces-3.4.1.jar, tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar,ezmorph-1.0.6.jar, commons-io-2.1.jar, commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar`

Comment: Which server impl/version? I have the impression that it already ships with JSF out the box given the odd implementation version string and the absence of JSTL JAR file in /WEB-INF/lib. In such case you should absolutely not have JSF API/impl JARs in /WEB-INF/lib, unless you intend to upgrade the server-bundled JSF from the webapp on (but that requires some specific settings and therefore knowledge of it which you didn't cover anywhere in the question)

Comment: @BalusC   My server version is Oracle WebLogic 12C. Please help me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: WebLogic as being a Java EE container already ships with JSF bundled as part of Java EE. Remove the both JSF JARs from /WEB-INF/lib and retry. They're colliding with WebLogic-bundled JSF which may expose in this kind of problems.

Comment: @BalusC   I removed both jar from said location but still the issue is same.

Comment: @BalusC   Isn't this the same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797231/why-does-postconstruct-callback-fire-every-time-even-though-bean-is-viewscoped)   error

Comment: You're dealing with two different beans here: `plan` and `planOverlay`. Which bean's `@PostConstruct` is being called?

Comment: @kolossus The `plan` is an object inside the `planOverlay` bean. The `@PostConstruct` is is being call to `planOverlay` bean. Confirmed.

Comment: if `plan` is inside `planOverlay`, why is it not being referenced as `planOverlay.plan`? Is the `f:ajax` the first point at which `planOverlay` is being referenced on that page? If that's the case, I would expect the `@PostConstruct` to be called first there

Comment: @kolossus   When my page load I want to retrieve all the plans from DB. This code is inside the `@PostConstruct`. So I don't want to call it over and over. This is the issue.  `f:ajax` call is to set the plan which user select.

Comment: @BalusC     Don't you help me further? I'm still having this dilemma

Comment: The problem is not visible in the information provided so far. It works just fine for me when tested in a blank playground project with most minimal configuration and using most recent versions.

Comment: @BalusC  isn't it relate to [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797231/why-does-postconstruct-callback-fire-every-time-even-though-bean-is-viewscoped)   ?

Comment: I asked you "Does the problem also manifest when you've only a `<h:body><h:form><h:selectBooleanCheckbox><f:ajax>` in a test page?". You answered "Yes". So that problem isn't related.

Comment: @BalusC I'm sorry I didn't see that this should done in a test page. Today I tried with another bean and a page in the same project. It is not calling the `@PostConstruct` again. what could be the reason to call it in that particular page only?

Comment: Well, create a MCVE. If you have no clue how to do that, carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that case,we should check if it is postback or ajaxRequest.
If your bean is viewScoped,you can add below code to your post-construct method.

Maybe it is not the best case but it works.

Also you can use JSF 2 PreRenderViewEvent for some initialization for bean.

```
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
            if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
       //Some initialization  
        } 
}
```

Comment: A view scoped bean should just not be recreated on every ajax request on the same view. This is not the normal behavior.

Comment: I agree with you.I used that control for some primefaces components which causes recreated on every ajax request on the same view.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your bean session scoped, so the `@PostConstruct` gets called only once per session. When bean is request scoped, like yours is judging by the behavior, it is created for each request which results in `init()` getting called also for each request.

**EDIT**

The suggestion was based on the assumption that the bean is request scoped, and that `init()` should be called once per session/view. OP's comment proved the assumption wrong.

Comment: At present the bean scope is `ViewScoped`. So it should work right? as I am in the same view.

Comment: It should work if it is view scoped, but it behaves like it is request scoped. How did you configure its scope? Can you try, just for debugging purpose,  with session scope?

Comment: Making it session scoped is bad advice.

Comment: @BalusC I know, I said just for debugging purpose, to check if maybe scope configuration is wrong

Comment: @PredragMaric, then state so... Mention that it might be that the scope is to short and refer to several existing SO posts about scopes. Beginners tend to take statements like your in your answer as 'how it should be done'. And with `ViewScoped` it can even be the 'wrong' one

Comment: @Kukeltje I wrote that it should work with view scope, and I also wrote that session scope should be tried just for debugging purposes. If you have other idea how an answer to this question should look like, post your own.

Comment: @PredragMaric     I update the question. Added the the class details and how I define the `ViewScope`.

Comment: @everalian Strange. Can you check if session is kept between HTTP calls to the server? Check if session cookies are sent along with each request.

Comment: @PredragMaric   how to check the things you said?

Comment: @everalian From browser. If you are using Chrome, press F12 and switch to Network tab. When you click on checkbox, a new request will be displayed in the list below. Click on it, then Cookies tab, it will display what cookies are sent to the server with the request. Check if there is a cookie named `JSESSIONID`. Similar instructions for other browsers.

Comment: @PredragMaric  `Cookies` tab is empty. But I found it in the `Header` Tab
`JSESSIONID=j6GcVMJDts90T42DXhH49xCbZmXnKrH2tVhc5FqVQSvLQbL2Ghql!-928136128`

Comment: @everalian Does the value change with each request?

Comment: @PredragMaric   No, Value is same. But pls note. I change the code to `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox><f:ajax>` now as requested by `BalusC`

Comment: @everalian I'm out of ideas, sorry. And I don't have a project at my hands right now where I could test this.

Comment: @PredragMaric No worries, Thanks for the effort so far. May I know what are you trying to isolate with the jsessionid? what if it has different ID per request?

Comment: @everalian I read that some web containers use different session ids to each request for unauthenticated users, as a measure against session fixation attacks. I think that would explain the behavior you are seeing.